# Run different task depending on host via playbook

Tags: ansible

I am pretty new to ansible, please be gentle if this is an obvious question.  I have a playbook that I use to perform an initial configuration/hardening of CentOS systems after installation.  I have 3 different groups of servers, and they all get configured in mostly the same way, with only a few differences in configuration files.  In particular, each group of servers needs to get its own unique iptables configuration.  How can I use a single playbook to send iptables1 to hostgroup1, iptables2 to hostgroup2 and iptables3 to hostgroup3 and still run all the other tasks on every server?

```
---
 - name: Initial OS configuration
   hosts: all
   remote_user: myuser
   sudo: yes
   tasks:
    - name: Deploy sshd_config
      copy: src=/opt/ansible/files/sshd_config dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config owner=root group=root mode=600
      register: sshd

    - name: Restart sshd service
      service: name=sshd state=restarted
      when: sshd.changed

    # HELP HERE
    - name: Deploy iptables
      copy: src=/opt/ansible/files/iptables1 dest=/etc/sysconfig/iptables owner=root group=root mode=600
      register: iptables

    - name: Restart iptables service
      service: name=iptables state=restarted
      when: iptables.changed

    - name: Set bash history timestamp
      copy: src=/opt/ansible/files/history.sh dest=/etc/profile.d/history.sh mode=644 owner=root group=root

    - name: Install screen
      yum: name=screen state=latest
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it is to use variables, in your inventory:

```
[group1:vars]
iptable_path=/opt/ansible/files/iptables1

[group2:vars]
iptable_path=/opt/ansible/files/iptables2

[group3:vars]
iptable_path=/opt/ansible/files/iptables3
```

Then, in the playbook:

```
...
- name: Deploy iptables
  copy: src={{ iptable_path }} dest=/etc/sysconfig/iptables owner=root group=root mode=600
  register: iptables
...
```

Comment: Is there a way to access the group name from ansible vars?

Comment: It seems there's no variable referring the "current" group. The closest thing is "group_names", listing all the groups the current host belongs to. See http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up with, using the "group_names" suggestion from 0xFC:

```
---
 - name: Initial OS configuration
   hosts: all
   remote_user: myuser
   sudo: yes
   tasks:

    ...

    - name: Deploy iptables to group1
      copy: src=/opt/ansible/files/iptables1 dest=/etc/sysconfig/iptables owner=root group=root mode=600
      register: iptables
      when: "'group1' in group_names"

    - name: Deploy iptables to group2
      copy: src=/opt/ansible/files/iptables2 dest=/etc/sysconfig/iptables owner=root group=root mode=600
      register: iptables
      when: "'group2' in group_names"

    - name: Deploy iptables to group3
      copy: src=/opt/ansible/files/iptables3 dest=/etc/sysconfig/iptables owner=root group=root mode=600
      register: iptables
      when: "'group3' in group_names"

    - name: Restart iptables service
      service: name=iptables state=restarted
      when: iptables.changed

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, I was looking for this.